# Disable hold but allow click in html(mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps

I am making a pwa for mobile and you can hold a button with your finger then a popup will come with the standard "copy linkadress" "copy text" "share link" etc.

How can I disable the popup thingy without disabling the click function. The button redirects to a different site

`<a class="Button-one" title="Relevant Title" href="HTML/test.html">BTN-1</a>`
html code for the button.

With css i can obviously use `pointer-events: none;`but that will also remove the main purpose of a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the context menu that appears on mobile devices when a user holds a button, you can use the `contextmenu` event in JavaScript. The `contextmenu` event is triggered when the context menu is about to be shown, and you can prevent it from being shown by calling the `preventDefault` method on the event object.

```js
document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Your click handling code here
});
```

Comment: If the solution works, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that future readers can also understand that the question has been resolved.